# Getting error when using EntityState.Modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article to implement repository pattern in a web API project. When implementing the update method in the repository I've followed the example provided, using:

```
context.Entry<Item>(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

For some reason though I'm getting the following build error,

> an instance of type system.data.entitystate can not be assigned to a
>   variable of type system.data.entity.entitystate

My code is the same as in the example other than the fact I am using a different entity to the one used in the example. Any ideas why I might be getting this error? I'm using EF 6.02.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is very clear, you are using the wrong types, you just need to write:

```
context.Entry<Item>(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

The `System.Data.Entity.EntityState` is living in the EF's `EntityFramework.dll` while the `System.Data.EntityState` is living in the `System.Data.Entity.dll`.

Since EF6 there is no need to reference the `System.Data.Entity.dll` (which contains some parts of the EntityFramework which where needed in the previous EF versions).

So you can just remove the `System.Data.Entity.dll` reference (which is added automatically by Visual Studio when creating a new project) to avoid these type mismatch errors in the future.

Comment: Oh dear, how embarrassing! I can only blame tiredness. :-) Thanks.